# ShellNew Regedit Key is doing nothing

Tags: regedit

I would like to add the "c" file in the "New File" button in the Resources Explorer by the System Register Editor:
I followed a tutorial on how to add options to the "New File" button in the Resources Explorer, and I added a "NewFile" Value in the ".c>ShellNew" Key I just made, with the value Template.c, after creating an empty file in the folder Windows>ShellNew (The folder is correct since I have AutoHotkey installed and there is "Template.ahk").

```
This is the register structure:
│ ├─.c
│ │  ├OpenWithProgids
│ │  ├PersistentHandler
│ │  └ShellNew

And these are the Values in each Key:
OpenWithProgids:    (Default)   REG_SZ      (value not set)
PersistentHandler:  (Default)   REG_SZ      {5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}
ShellNew:           (Default)   REG_SZ      (value not set)
                    FileName    REG_SZ      Template.c
```

My default handler for ".c" files is Notepad++.

I would like to know if the infos I provided are enough to solve the problem, and I am sorry if I have chosen the wrong platform to ask, I am new to coding, Register editing and Stack Overflow in general.

Comment: Try to put "txtfile" as default value for the .c key

Comment: .C    (Default)   REG_SZ      txtfile

Comment: Before I changed it, it was c_auto_file. Now it works, thanks, but the name of the file is "New Text Document", and I wish to know if there's a way to change it. Also, I am curious to know how and why setting this value made it work. Thank you again for helping!